# R: How to split string into pieces

Tags: r, strsplit

I'm trying to split tons of strings as below:

```
x = "�\001�\001�\001�\001�\001\002CN�\001\bShandong�\001\004Zibo�\002$ABCDEFGHIJK�\002\aIMG_HAS�\002�\002�\002�\002�\002�\002�\002�\002\02413165537405763268743�\002\001�\002�\002�\002�\003�\003�\003����\005�\003�\003�\003�\003"
```

into four pieces

```
'CN', 'Shandong', 'Zibo', 'ABCDEFGHIJK'
```

I've tried

```
stringr::str_split(x, '\\00.')
```

which output the origin `x`.
Also,

```
trimws(gsub("�\\00?", "", x, perl = T))
```

which only removes the unknown character `�`.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `str_extract_all` :

```
stringr::str_extract_all(x, '[A-Za-z_]+')[[1]]
[1] "CN"          "Shandong"    "Zibo"        "ABCDEFGHIJK" "IMG_HAS"
```

With base R :

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr('[A-Za-z_]+', x))[[1]]
```

Here we extract all the words with upper, lower case or an underscore. Everything else is ignored so characters like `�\\00?` are not there in final output.

Comment: You are amazing! It works. Could you explain a little bit about the code?

Comment: I added some explanation of the code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` from `base R`

```
setdiff(strsplit(x, "[^A-Za-z]+")[[1]], "")
#[1] "CN"          "Shandong"    "Zibo"        "ABCDEFGHIJK" "IMG"         "HAS"
```